# Compilation by g++ of parser code created by bison fails because `yytokentype` enum values are not visible

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, bison, minizinc

I'm trying to compile [chuffed](https://github.com/chuffed/chuffed) on Linux with

- gcc-c++-10.3.1-1.fc33.x86_64
- flex-2.6.4-5.fc33.x86_64
- bison-3.6.4-3.fc33.x86_64

This is a CMAKE managed installation.

As desribed in [the README](https://github.com/chuffed/chuffed), starting in the toplevel directory of the distribution, I run:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --verbose
```

At this point, errors appear. The creation of the parser code seems to work. Then `/usr/bin/c++` is invoked with the option `-std=gnu++11`. It terminates with:

```
parser.tab.cpp: In function ‘int yyparse(void*)’:
parser.tab.cpp:1963:12: error: ‘YYEMPTY’ was not declared in this scope
 1963 |   yychar = YYEMPTY; /* Cause a token to be read.  */
      |            ^~~~~~~
parser.tab.cpp:2077:17: error: ‘YYEOF’ was not declared in this scope
 2077 |   if (yychar <= YYEOF)
      |                 ^~~~~
parser.tab.cpp:2083:22: error: ‘YYerror’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘yyerror’?
 2083 |   else if (yychar == YYerror)
      |                      ^~~~~~~
      |                      yyerror
parser.tab.cpp:2089:16: error: ‘YYUNDEF’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘YYUSE’?
 2089 |       yychar = YYUNDEF;
      |                ^~~~~~~
      |                YYUSE
parser.tab.cpp:3650:21: error: ‘YYEOF’ was not declared in this scope
 3650 |       if (yychar <= YYEOF)
      |                     ^~~~~
```

In the source, the constants which the compiler is looking for are defined in an enum:

```
/* Token kinds.  */
#ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
# define YYTOKENTYPE
  enum yytokentype
  {
    YYEMPTY = -2,
    YYEOF = 0,                     /* "end of file"  */
    YYerror = 256,                 /* error  */
    YYUNDEF = 257,                 /* "invalid token"  */
    INT_LIT = 258,                 /* INT_LIT  */
    BOOL_LIT = 259,                /* BOOL_LIT  */
    FLOAT_LIT = 260,               /* FLOAT_LIT  */
    ID = 261,                      /* ID  */
    STRING_LIT = 262,              /* STRING_LIT  */
...
    WHERE = 301                    /* WHERE  */
  };
  typedef enum yytokentype yytoken_kind_t;
#endif
```

and used for example like this in `yyparse(void *parm)`:

```
  YYDPRINTF ((stderr, "Starting parse\n"));

  yychar = YYEMPTY; /* Cause a token to be read.  */
  goto yysetstate;
```

At first sight, there seems to be no cause for the compiler to complain. However, there might be something specific about the C++ version or the syntax used here. My C++ is very rusty, and this might be something straightforward.

I tried to change the line to

```
  yychar = yytokentype::YYEMPTY; /* Cause a token to be read.  */
```

but then I get:

```
parser.tab.cpp:1963:25: error: ‘YYEMPTY’ is not a member of ‘yytokentype’
 1963 |   yychar = yytokentype::YYEMPTY; /* Cause a token to be read.  */
```

That's even more perplexing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this so I guess more details about what you did are needed.

Comment: Are you on master? I think their master is broken and you are getting a wrong parser.tab.h or something. Run a verbose build and add `-H` compiler flag to see which headers are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the suggestion of [n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m),

assuming

```
CHUFFED_TOPDIR=... # toplevel of the distribution
```

we find that there is an existing `parser.tab.h` created with old-ish GNU Bison 3.0.4:

```
"$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.h
```

This file is indeed included during compilation, as can be ascertained when compiling like so, which causes the inclusion tree to be printed:

```
cd "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"
rm -rf build/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-H" cmake .. # using cmake to run cmake
cmake --build . --verbose
```

> **Note**
>
> The *usual* command line for running `cmake` would be:
>
> ```
> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR ..
> ```
>
> Definitely consider switching on debug mode for a first try.
> This is important for running the examples, which do not check
> their commandline arguments and segfault if these are
> missing . With debugging on, you at least get assertion
> error messages:
>
> ```
> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR \
>       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
> ```
>
> So, altogether
>
> ```
> cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-H" \
>    cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR
>          -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
> ```

Thus, try removing the `parser.tab.h` and, to make sure, the accompanying `parser.tab.cpp`:

```
mv "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.h \
   "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.h.bak

mv "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.cpp \
   "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.cpp.bak
```

A similar problem may exist for `lexer.yy.cpp`, and thus:

```
mv "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/lexer.yy.cpp \
   "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/chuffed/flatzinc/lexer.yy.cpp.bak
```

> **Note**
> It is always good to take a look at
>
> ```
> "$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
> ```
>
> but in my case it just says that looking for the pthread library
> failed, at least initially.

Compilation succeeds now. Bison output can be found as:

```
"$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/build/parser.tab.cpp
```

as well as:

```
"$CHUFFED_TOPDIR"/build/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.h
```

Note that in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, we find this code:

```
find_package(BISON)
if(BISON_FOUND)
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc)
  bison_target(FZNParser
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.yxx
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.tab.cpp
    DEFINES_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.h
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-l"
  )
else()
  message(WARNING "Bison cannot be run. Using cached file, which may be out of date.")
  set(BISON_FZNParser_OUTPUTS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc/parser.tab.h
  )
endif()

find_package(FLEX)
if(FLEX_FOUND)
  flex_target(FZNLexer
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc/lexer.lxx
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.yy.cpp
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-L"
  )
  add_flex_bison_dependency(FZNLexer FZNParser)
else()
  message(WARNING "Flex cannot be run. Using cached file, which may be out of date.")
  set(FLEX_FZNLexer_OUTPUTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/chuffed/flatzinc/lexer.yy.cpp)
endif()
```

I suppose the provided `parser.tab.h` should be automatically skipped if bison can be found on the compiling system. I'm not sure what's going wrong here.